# Using when validation yup on formik form

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, yup

Hey guy i have a problem with 2 form input number, min and max, i want the value of max alway greater than min value, if not, using yup to show error, but seem it doesnt work, here is my code. Thank for your help!!

```
const formikAddFilter = useFormik({
enableReinitialize: true,
initialValues: {
  filterName: '',
  min: 0,
  max: 0,
  unValidRange: max > min 
},
validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
  unValidRange:Yup.boolean(),
  filterName: Yup.string().required('Skill is required'),
  max:Yup.number().when('unValidRange',{
    is:true,
    then: Yup.number().required('max cant less than min')
  })
}),
onSubmit: values => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(values))
  setFilterItem([...filterItem, values])
  formikAddFilter.setFieldValue('filterName', '')
  formikAddFilter.setFieldValue('min', 0)
  formikAddFilter.setFieldValue('max', 0)
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const validationRange = yup.object().shape({
  min: yup.number().required(),
  max: yup
    .number()
    .required()
    .test('superior', 'min must be smaller than max', function(f) {
      const ref = yup.ref('min');
      return f > this.resolve(ref);
    })
});
```

**Demo:** [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rkrhqk)